# can't suspend to RAM any more after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend, ram

I upgraded to 14.04 and now my laptop can't "sleep" anymore i.e. suspend to RAM doesn't work. How can I figure out what's wrong and fix this?

**edit 1**

My hardware is a `ASUS Zenbook UX32A`

**edit 2**

Well, I don't have a script `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` on my machine.
I installed smartly and this is what I get:

```
$ sudo hibernate-ram
hibernate-ram:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
s2ram: unknown machine, see s2ram(8) and the USuspendRamForce option
hibernate-ram: Aborting.
$
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what you're exactly doing, what hardware you're using, etc.

Comment: @kraxor please see **edit 1** above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, seems like my problem got resolved after a reboot... now, that's odd... oh well... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this script from terminal:

```
sudo ./etc/acpi/sleep.sh
```

Also you can try [smartly puts your computer to sleep (suspend to RAM or disk)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/hibernate/)

```
sudo hibernate-ram
```

Comment: please see **edit 2** above

Comment: So far found [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that I was able to solve my suspend to RAM issue by installing `smartly` (search for "smartly", but it will show up as "hibernate" in the Synaptic Package Manager).

I installed `smartly`, restarted my machine, and tried to run `hibernate-ram` and `hibernate-disk` from the command line, but received the same errors as OP. HOWEVER, trying to suspend to ram via any normal method (closing laptop screen, choosing "suspend" from power menu) seems to work!

- Ubuntu 17.04 (w/ KDE package)
- Kernel 4.10.0-35-generic
- Dell XPS 13 (model 9350)